# Firebase database query returning same data for all endpoints

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I've tried to create a firebase function for sending push notification to all the devices when a new post is inserted to the Firebase Realtime Database. My device tokens are under the profile-notifications endpoint. When I try to execute my function by inserting a new post to the database my response is something unexpected. I read the docs from https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/ and https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database, but couldn't get much further. Here are my logs:

```html
5:23:47.451 PM debug sendNewPostNotification
  Function execution took 1145 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
 
5:23:47.447 PM info sendNewPostNotification
  p:0: from server: {"r":4,"b":{"s":"ok","d":""}}
 
5:23:47.446 PM info sendNewPostNotification
  p:0: from server: {"r":3,"b":{"s":"ok","d":{}}}
 
5:23:47.444 PM info sendNewPostNotification
  Result: T { A: P { k: Sb { Ka: [Function: vb], ba: [Object] }, aa: P { k: [Object], aa: null, wb: [Object], Bb: '' }, wb: Zc { ld: [Object], ac: [Object] }, Bb: null }, V: R { u: Gd { app: [Object], L: [Object], Ua: [Object], Sc: null, ca: [Object], td: 1, Qa: [Object], va: [Object], qg: [Object], jc: [Object], ee: [Object], md: [Object], ia: [Object], Xa: [Object], cd: 1, fe: null, K: [Object] }, path: J { o: [Object], Y: 0 }, m: Df { xa: false, ka: false, Ib: false, na: false, Pb: false, oa: 0, kb: '', bc: null, xb: '', Zb: null, vb: '', g: Tc {} }, Kc: false, then: undefined, catch: undefined }, g: Tc {} }
 
5:23:47.439 PM info sendNewPostNotification
  p:0: {"r":4,"a":"n","b":{"p":"/profile-notifications"}}
 
5:23:47.439 PM info sendNewPostNotification
  p:0: Unlisten on /profile-notifications for default
 
5:23:47.438 PM info sendNewPostNotification
  p:0: Unlisten called for /profile-notifications default
 
5:23:47.437 PM info sendNewPostNotification
  event: /profile-notifications:value:{"jane_doe@gmail*com":{"deviceToken2":true},"john_doe@gmail*com":{"deviceToken1":true}}
 
5:23:47.430 PM info sendNewPostNotification
  p:0: handleServerMessage d {"p":"profile-notifications","d":{"jane_doe@gmail*com":{"deviceToken2":true},"john_doe@gmail*com":{"deviceToken1":true}}}
 
5:23:47.429 PM info sendNewPostNotification
  p:0: from server: {"r":2,"b":{"s":"ok","d":{"auth":null,"expires":1491492227}}}
 
5:23:47.429 PM info sendNewPostNotification
  c:0:0: Primary connection is healthy.
 
5:23:47.290 PM info sendNewPostNotification
  p:0: from server: {"r":1,"b":{"s":"ok","d":""}}
 
5:23:47.289 PM info sendNewPostNotification
  p:0: {"r":3,"a":"q","b":{"p":"/profile-notifications","h":""}}
 
5:23:47.289 PM info sendNewPostNotification
  p:0: Listen on /profile-notifications for default
 
5:23:47.288 PM info sendNewPostNotification
  p:0: {"r":2,"a":"gauth","b":{"cred":"ya29.El0lBHwnjCRAbk5q-vLmvHyYlxEv7zKP03kvxA7ktrRQgHpDAhDxM0bkUwfHUNaAJUxK4n7MsS1tTqXBF35NojUCPeMB5CJAhxuI8iTvXEWLvQQW-rbjUwKCIXF9oCQ"}}
 
5:23:47.287 PM info sendNewPostNotification
  p:0: {"r":1,"a":"s","b":{"c":{"sdk.admin_node.4-2-0":1}}}
 
5:23:47.287 PM info sendNewPostNotification
  p:0: reportStats {"c":{"sdk.admin_node.4-2-0":1}}
 
5:23:47.285 PM info sendNewPostNotification
  p:0: connection ready
 
5:23:47.285 PM info sendNewPostNotification
  c:0:0: Realtime connection established.
 
5:23:47.283 PM info sendNewPostNotification
  c:0:0:1 Websocket connected.
 
5:23:47.262 PM info sendNewPostNotification
  c:0:0:1 Websocket connecting to wss://s-usc1c-nss-135.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5&ns=rally-zone
 
5:23:47.262 PM info sendNewPostNotification
  c:0:0:0 Websocket connection was disconnected.
 
5:23:47.259 PM info sendNewPostNotification
  c:0:0:0 WebSocket is being closed
 
5:23:47.259 PM info sendNewPostNotification
  c:0:0: Shutting down all connections
 
5:23:47.259 PM info sendNewPostNotification
  c:0:0: Reset packet received. New host: s-usc1c-nss-135.firebaseio.com
 
5:23:47.254 PM info sendNewPostNotification
  c:0:0:0 Websocket connected.
 
5:23:47.167 PM info sendNewPostNotification
  c:0:0:0 Websocket connecting to wss://rally-zone.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5
 
5:23:47.165 PM info sendNewPostNotification
  c:0:0: Connection created
 
5:23:47.164 PM info sendNewPostNotification
  getToken() completed. Creating connection.
 
5:23:47.162 PM info sendNewPostNotification
  p:0: Auth token refreshed
 
5:23:47.101 PM info sendNewPostNotification
  p:0: Making a connection attempt
 
5:23:47.099 PM info sendNewPostNotification
  p:0: Listen called for /profile-notifications default
 
5:23:47.084 PM info sendNewPostNotification
  p:0: Browser went online.
 
5:23:46.307 PM debug sendNewPostNotification
  Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions
 
5:23:46.307 PM debug sendNewPostNotification
  Function execution started
```

So from what I can see, the response from the database is what I expect, but when I try to log my result, I get a long json with nothing close to what I was expecting. Could this be because I don't have a billing account? Can somebody help me on this? Here is my code as well.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNewPostNotification = functions.database.ref('/posts/{postId}').onWrite(event => {
  const postId = event.params.postId;

  admin.database.enableLogging(true);
  return admin.database().ref("profile-notifications").once('value').then(result => {
    if (result) {
      console.log('Result: ', result); // "Stuff worked!"
    }
  }, err => {
    console.log('Error: ', err); // Error: "It broke"
  });
});
```

Comment: `results` is a [`DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot) object and logging that is going to be a bunch of minified code. Try logging [`result.val()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot#val) instead to get the actual value you want.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jacobawenger pointed out in the comment, the problem was, that the `result` was a `DataSnapshot`, so I needed to add `result.val()` to get the value of it.